# How to append new elements to iframes in jquery

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm trying to clone elements in a facebook iframe and append it back to its parent.

The first thing I did was to select the element that I want to clone(I'm using chrome dev tools):

```
var clone = $($0).clone();
```

Then selected its parent:

```
var parent =  $($0).parent();
```

Then appended the clone back to the parent:

```
clone.appendTo(parent);
```

But I got this one:

[image]

As you can see it doesn't actually append to the iframe but in the parent variable.
Is there something wrong with my approach? Does facebook not allow this? I just need to make a few clones for a dummy account because I don't want to trouble my friends. All I need to do is to send out a few invites to use a facebook app so I was thinking of cloning a dummy account on the friend selection.

I'm talking about the request dialog:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Comment: I think you shouldn't try to access an iframes content. iframes don't allow this. What can be done is accessing parent window FROM an iframe, which you can't since you don't control the code in the iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access a facebook iframe from outside the frame because of [same-origin security restrictions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) in a browser.  You will not be able to copy or modify the DOM in the iframe if it is served from a different domain than the host page.

Answer (score 1):

> All I need to do is to send out a few invites to use a facebook app so I was thinking of cloning a dummy account on the friend selection.

Whatever that actually means – its definitively the wrong approach.

If you want to test functionality of your app – use test user accounts for that. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/